Tin "lagoon" on PCB - possible solder mask removal?
I was desoldering the PCB of a SATA connector and I got it off just fine. I happened to go over the solder and in some parts of the PCB, it looks like the solder mask has come off. There are no raised pads, rings or traces to be seen and I was very careful not to apply excessive heat.
Would reapplying UV mask on that area be enough or should I be worried?



Those areas don't appear to be connecting anything that wasn't already supposed to be connected together, so I don't think you need to do anything.

@Hearth That's what I thought. why has this happened? I ask to learn. Thank you

Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solder_mask  The final step of the solder mask processing is a thermal or ultraviolet cure. If curing was not appropriate, the solder mask may be detached during desoldering.

Considering it's not probably GND, because it seems that GND is the first pad from right, you should put some kapton tape for some security, but not worth to reapply UV mask if you have to buy it.

If you're concerned about the soldermask for aesthetic reasons (e.g. if it's a classic computer that you're restoring), I believe you can get a green nail polish that works as a passable substitute. If you're not concerned about aesthetics, kapton tape as samuel suggests would be perfectly sufficient to prevent shorts.
